# Styles for mat-input work only after page refresh

Tags: angular-material, angular12

In the project, we used angular material and created a theme for it. Everything is defined globaly (`src/styles/theme.scss` and theme file is imported to `src/styles.scss`) so that changes are available everywhere.

[image]

Unfortunately, there is a race because the inputs are displayed correctly only after refreshing the page.

[image]

how I style the components:

```
mat-form-field {

  .mat-form-field-flex {
    border: 1px solid $form-border--color;
  }
  ...
}
```